# Use same require-config file between page and r.js optimizer?

Tags: requirejs

Is there a way to have the page and r.js use the same build.js?

The format for the config file for r.js is wrapped only with

```
({
  //..
})
```

Or just `{ /*...*/}`

But that format can't be used as a require configuration. If I add a `require.config` at the beginning of the `build.js` then `r.js` doesn't accept it as an argument anymore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can point your `build.js` to a file that contains the `require.config()` values:

```
mainConfigFile: '../some/path/to/main.js'
```

Explained here - https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L27